# How can I use a report snapshot in a dashboard

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dashboard

I have a Dynamics 2011 Dashboard with a link to and SSRS report via an iFrame. It works well, but the report I am viewing is slow to refresh. I'd like to schedule the report and have the dashboard automatically point to the *latest* snapshot.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Ryan

Comment: Have you looked at [SSRS Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx)? I think it may do just what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have control over when the report is refreshed - like 3am in the morning - you should use a snapshot.  You need to assign default parameters and then set the execution settings for the report in SSRS report manager.

If having the report re-run throughout the day is acceptable, you can use the caching option, also in the execution settings in SSRS report manager.  Once the cache has expired for your report, the next user that runs it will have to wait.